# chrooted sftp user with write permissions to /var/www

Tags: debian, file-permissions, apache-http-server, sftp, chroot

I am getting confused about this setup that I am trying to deploy. 
I hope someone of you folks can lend me a hand: much much appreciated.

**Background info**

Server is Debian 6.0, ext3, with Apache2/SSL and Nginx at the front as reverse proxy. 
I need to provide sftp access to the Apache root directory (/var/www), making sure that the sftp user is chrooted to that path with RWX permissions.

All this without modifying any default permission in /var/www.

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 Nov  4 22:46 www
```

Inside /var/www

```
-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data     177 Mar 11  2012 file1
drwxr-x--- 6 www-data www-data    4096 Sep 10  2012 dir1
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data    4096 Sep 28  2012 dir2
-rw------- 1 root     root          19 Apr  6  2012 file2
-rw------- 1 root     root     3548528 Sep 28  2012 file3
drwxr-x--- 6 www-data www-data    4096 Aug 22 00:11 dir3
drwxr-x--- 5 www-data www-data    4096 Jul 15  2012 dir4
drwxr-x--- 2 www-data www-data  536576 Nov 24  2012 dir5
drwxr-x--- 2 www-data www-data    4096 Nov  5 00:00 dir6
drwxr-x--- 2 www-data www-data    4096 Nov  4 13:24 dir7
```

**What I have tried**

1. created a new group *secureftp*
2. created a new sftp user, joined to *secureftp* and *www-data* groups also with *nologin* shell. Homedir is /
3. edited sshd_config with

> ```
> Subsystem sftp internal-sftp 
> AllowTcpForwarding no 
> Match Group <secureftp> 
>       ChrootDirectory /var/www 
>       ForceCommand internal-sftp
> ```

I can login with the sftp user, list files but no write action is allowed. 
Sftp user is in the www-data group but permissions in /var/www are read/read+x for the group bit so... It doesn't work.

I've also tried with ACL, but as I apply ACL RWX permissions for the sftp user to /var/www (dirs and files recursively), it will change the unix permissions as well which is what I don't want.

What can I do here?

I was thinking I could enable the user www-data to login as sftp, so that it'll be able to modify files/dirs that www-data owns in /var/www. 
But for some reason I think this would be a stupid move securitywise.

Comment: I dont think it is possible without changing the permission.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What I've done is to chroot my users to their home directories and then used `mount --bind` to create a link to it in their home directories.

I then used `setfacl` to make sure `www-data` maintans write permissions on new files in the directory. This effect will recurse into `/var/www`, which is what you want to do.

By setting `g+s` on the directory, all new files and directories created within it will inherit the group ownership from its parent.

```
useradd someuser
mkdir -p /home/someuser/www
mount --bind /var/www /home/someuser/www
chmod g+s /home/someuser/www
chown -R someuser:www-data /home/someuser/www
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /home/someuser/www
```

That should do the trick.

#### Make your mounts persistent

Obviously you want your mounts to still be there when you reboot the server. It's as simple as adding the mounts to your `/etc/fstab`. Not all providers let you touch this file, but most do.

Just add lines like this:

```
/var/www        /home/someuser/www        none        bind        0        0
```

You might want to reboot to make sure it works.

Comment: Fact is that when you chmod g+s /home/someuser/www and chown someuser:www-data /home/someuser/www it'll also transfer the same permissions and owner:group to /var/www. This is due to the mount --bind. Thanks a--lot!

Comment: Where can I pay you a beer? Looks like it's all good, and Apache doesn't seem to complain about sftp-user as the owner of /var/www. I was very close to your solution when I went the ACL way, but I left the suid part out: you're magic, thanks!